# Custom Validation in Codeigniter in controller level

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to use Custom Validation in controller-side . I want to use form-validator of CI in validation.

Note: I will use that validation for web services. ( That's why it will stay on controller level )

I tried to do like that, is it acceptable format  ?

```
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('$userFullName', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('$userNickName', 'UserNickname', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('$userEmail', 'Email', 'trim|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('$userPassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|');

           if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       { 
            if(!$this->validate_member->set_message($userFullName,'userFullName', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean'))
            {

                $error_code = '102';

            } else if (!$this->validate_member->set_message($userNickName,'userNickName', 'UserNickname', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean')){

                $error_code = '103';

            } else if (!$this->validate_member->set_message($userEmail, 'Email', 'trim|valid_email')){

                $error_code = '104';

            } else if(!$this->validate_member->set_message($userEmail, '$userPassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|')){

                $error_code = '105';

            } else {

                $error_code = '106';

            }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set custom validation in Form_validation.php located in system>libaries which you can set up new function name and a new validation and set the error message in the language.

Comment: the main issue is the , i cannot handle the custom errors, I wanna catch $userFullName that needs 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean' , and if return false i wanna print the error with jSon format ..